# How can I load an SKBitmap from a local image

Tags: maui

I'm pretty new to MAUI and .Net in general. However, I'm trying to load an image stored under Resources/Images as an SKBitmap.

The crux of what I'm trying to do is that I have a custom control that's written in C#, and part of this custom control needs to dynamically render an image.

```
 private void LoadImage()
{
    Image image = new Image
    {
        Source = ImageSource.FromFile("pain_man.png")
    };
    _preloadedBitmap = ConvertToSkBitmap(image);
}

private SKBitmap ConvertToSkBitmap(Image image)
{
    if (image.Source is FileImageSource fileImageSource)
    {
        return SKBitmap.Decode(fileImageSource);
    }
    return null;
}
```

If I debug it, it looks like the underlying Stream is null, which down in `SKFileStream.OpenStream` the path argument to

`SKFileStream skFileStream = new SKFileStream(path);`

is just `pain_man.png`. So, it makes sense that it wouldn't find the file. I'm assuming that when I do something like

`<Image Source="pain_man.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" />`

there is some behind-the-scenes magic that turns this into an absolute path?

Or maybe I'm just going about this the completely wrong way?

Comment: A resource is not a file.  Use FromResource

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.